# Buffering stdin & stdout

Tags: c

I have this simple peace of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    fprintf(stdout , "stdout \n");
    fprintf(stderr , "stduerr \n");
    return 0;
}

Output:
stdout
stderr
```

I know that stdout is buffered and stderr is not and know a bout newline flushing

the result on Windows and netbeans is :

```
stdout
stderr
```

the result using mac and Eclipse :

```
stderr
stdout
```

and Want to know why ...

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: Both of your strings end in newline, and the output buffering for `stdout` is line-based so it's immediately flushed.

Comment: I think the output is correct, your expectations do not match with reality.

Comment: You were expecting such output based on what exactly?

Comment: You say you see this in ide, ide may implement buffering in their own way, if you see that in buildin console window.

Comment: the same code on mac and using Eclipse IDE give me stderr and then stdout and I know a bout newline , So I get confused ...

Comment: based on try Andre because I try this code on mac and eclipse first and want to know if the OS or the IDE have an effect on the result or it's just maybe a bug in the Eclipse ...

Comment: Probably because Eclipse's console doesn't count as a terminal so you don't get the default line-buffering.

Answer (score 1):

`stdout` by default (on your system anyways) is line buffered, meaning it will flush either when you flush it, or when you put a newline character '\n' in it, which you do here:

```
fprintf(stdout , "stdout \n");
```

More on the buffering of stdout:

> If stdout is known to not refer to an interactive device, the stream
>   is fully buffered. Otherwise, it is library-dependent whether the
>   stream is line buffered or not buffered by default (see setvbuf).

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdout/)

Comment: That's not generally true, for example in a standard linux environment stdout is only linebuffered if it is a terminal. Otherwise, it is block buffered

Comment: No, stdout is not line buffered by default on the OPs system(s). Its line buffered on his Windows system when running within Netbeans, and it's fully buffered when running on Linux and Mac within Eclipse. (It would be line buffered if he ran the program in a terminal/console on Linux and Mac too).

Answer (score 0):

With `stdio(3)` output streams that refer to terminal devices are line buffered like `stdout`, while `stderr` is not buffered.

The program above exits immediately after fprintf, so `stdout` is flushed then.

If you want to see the differences in behavior, redirect the stdout and stderr to a file, and add a few more `fprintf` lines.

Comment: `stdout` may or may not be line-buffered by default.  It's implementation-dependent.

Comment: I edit the question ... I know a bout flushing the newline my problem is the same code give different result on both systems and IDEs and want to know why ...

Answer (score 0):

As others already noted, you will get the result you expected if you use

```
fprintf(stdout, "STDOUT");

fprintf(stderr, "STDERR");
```

This is because the default Linux terminal stdout is line buffered while stderr is not buffered.

You will need to flush stdout or to manually print a '\n' to stdout before the print to stderr. Then you will see it before the stderr message.

Note that it is also possible to turn off buffering for stdout.